# When I install my apk I get an icon for every class in the project

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have a project in Eclipse with maybe 7 different classes that i open with Intent.  The problem is when I install the .apk on my HTC phone I get an icon for every class.  How do I make the project so it installs as one app only?  /Johan Andersson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, as mreichelt said you have to remove this lines from each class declared on your Manifest except from the one you want to be the main Activity :D

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! It works like a charm. Now I can impress the boss with a new app tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one activity to be started from the launcher, just remove the intent filters for all other activities than your wanted one in your manifest. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#ifilters